# How to plot a histogram of a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, time-series

I have a list of times

```
times = ['2022-12-09T16:06:34.000000000', '2022-12-09T16:06:34.000000000',
       '2022-12-09T16:09:47.000000000', ... , '2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000',
       '2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000', '2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000',
       '2022-12-09T17:49:10.000000000', '2022-12-09T17:49:10.000000000']
```

and I want to plot the number of occurrences per hour in a histogram using matplotlib.pyplot.

What I've done is this:

```
times = pd.Series(extract_times()).astype("datetime64")
times.groupby([times.dt.day, times.dt.hour]).count()
times.plot()
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

I would like a more linear time scale on the x axis, and preferrably a rolling average, or bars alternatively.

Answer (score 2):

With the following toy Series:

```py
import pandas as pd

times = [
    "2022-12-09T16:06:34.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T16:06:34.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T16:09:47.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T17:46:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T17:49:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T17:49:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T18:46:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T19:49:10.000000000",
    "2022-12-09T19:49:10.000000000",
]

times = pd.Series(times).astype("datetime64")
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
times.groupby([times.dt.day, times.dt.hour]).count().plot(kind="bar").set_xticklabels(
    times.dt.hour.unique(), rotation=0
)
```

Outputs in a Jupyter notebook:

[image]